# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: jpa, session, transactions

This method begins with Transaction

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Account generateDirectCustomerAccountEntity(AccountReq source, Map<String, String> headers, String workflowId) {
    Account dbAccount = dCustomerModelToEntityMapper.map(source, headers);
    dbAccount = saveAccount(source, dbAccount, headers, workflowId);
    return dbAccount;
}
```

This is a mapper class where I create a DB Account entity and map addresses and contacts.

```
@Override
@LogExecutionTime(log=true)
public Account map(AccountReq accountReq, Map<String, String> headers) {
        logger.info("AccountModelToEntityMapper.mapDirectCustomer*****START");
        Account dbAccount = new Account();
        AccountCode accountCode = dbService.getAccountCodeForDirectCustomer(accountReq);
        String accountId = dbService.genarateAccountId(accountCode);
        logger.info("genarated AccountID for Direct Customer is={}", accountId);
        dbAccount.setAccountId(accountId);
        setAccountContact(dbAccount, accountReq, headers);
        setAddress(dbAccount, accountReq);
        dbAccount.setAccountType(accountCode.getCodeId());
        return dbAccount;
}
```

When I don't call the below method inside the map, everything works fine. But when I call it I get the error described in the title.

```
private void setAccountContact(Account dbAccount, AccountReq accountReq, Map<String, String> headers) {

    try {
        if (null != accountReq.getContacts() && !accountReq.getContacts().isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("setAccountContact accountReq.getContacts().size()={}", accountReq.getContacts().size());
            List<String> emailList=new ArrayList<>();
            for (ContactReq contact : accountReq.getContacts()) {
                String email = contact.getEmail();
                logger.info("setAccountContact:"+email);
                if(emailList.contains(email)) {
                    logger.error("ERROR={}", "same emailId sent in multiple contacts");
                    throw new AccountException(AccountConstant.INVALID_FIELDS, AccountConstant.INVALID_FIELDS_CODE);
                
                }
                emailList.add(email);
                Contact dbcontact = contactRepository.findByEmail(email);
                if (null == dbcontact) {
                    dbcontact = new Contact();
                    dbcontact.setCreatedAt(dbAccount.getCreatedAt());
                    dbcontact.setCreatedBy(dbAccount.getCreatedBy());
                    dbcontact.setEmail(contact.getEmail());
                    dbcontact.setFirstName((contact.getFirstName()));
                    dbcontact.setLastName((contact.getLastName()));
                    dbcontact.setPhone(contact.getPhoneNumber());
                    dbcontact.setStatus(AccountConstant.STATUS_ACTIVE);
                    logger.info("contactRepository={} {}", contactRepository,contact.getEmail());

                    try {
                        dbcontact = contactRepository.save(dbcontact);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        logger.error("ERROR in updating contact table={}", e);
                        throw new InternalServerException(AccountConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                                AccountConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_CODE);
                    }
                }


                AccountContact dbAccountContact = new AccountContact();
                dbAccountContact.setCreatedAt(dbAccount.getCreatedAt());
                dbAccountContact.setCreatedBy(dbAccount.getCreatedBy());
                dbAccountContact.setStatus(AccountConstant.STATUS_ACTIVE);
                ContactRole contactRole = getContactRole(contact.getType());
                if (null == contactRole) {
                    logger.error("ERROR={}", "contact type is invalid");
                    throw new AccountException(AccountConstant.INVALID_FIELDS, AccountConstant.INVALID_FIELDS_CODE);
                }
                dbAccountContact.setContactRole(contactRole);
                dbAccountContact.setAccount(dbAccount);
                dbAccountContact.setContact(dbcontact);
                if (null != dbcontact.getAccountContact() && !dbcontact.getAccountContact().isEmpty()) {

                    logger.error("dbcontact.getAccountContact() is not null, dbcontact.getAccountContact().size()={}",
                            dbcontact.getAccountContact().size());  

                    List<AccountContact> accountContactList = dbcontact.getAccountContact();
                    accountContactList.add(dbAccountContact);
                } else {
                    logger.error("getAccountStatusHistory is null");
                    List<AccountContact> accountContactList = new ArrayList<>();
                    accountContactList.add(dbAccountContact);
                    dbcontact.setAccountContact(accountContactList);
                }
                
            
                    if (null != contact && AccountConstant.ADMIN_CONTACT_ROLE.equalsIgnoreCase(contact.getType())) {
                        if (null != contact.getAdminId()) {
                            dbService.saveExternalID(String.valueOf(dbcontact.getContactId()), contact.getAdminId(), headers, AccountConstant.STATUS_ACTIVE,
                                    CosConstants.ID_TYPE);
                        }
                    }
                

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("ERROR in setAccountContact to dbAccount contacts={},{}", accountReq.getContacts(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}

@LogExecutionTime(log = true)
public Account saveDirectCustomerAccount(AccountReq source, Account dbAccount, Map<String, String> headers, String workflowId) {
    
        try {
            String statusCode=AccountConstant.INITIAL_STATUS_CODE;
            dbAccount = updateAccountStatusHistory(dbAccount, statusCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error("ERROR in updateAccountStatusHistory={}", e);
            throw new InternalServerException(AccountConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    AccountConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_CODE);
        }

        return dbAccount;
    }

@LogExecutionTime(log = true)
private Account updateAccountStatusHistory(Account dbAccount, String statusCode) {

    logger.info("updateAccountStatusHistory *****START");
    AccountStatusHistory accountStatusHistory = new AccountStatusHistory();
    accountStatusHistory.setAccount(dbAccount);
    accountStatusHistory.setCreatedAt(dbAccount.getCreatedAt());
    accountStatusHistory.setCreatedBy(dbAccount.getCreatedBy());
    try {
        updateAccountStatus(dbAccount, statusCode, accountStatusHistory);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("ERROR updateAccountStatus e={}", e);
    }

    if (null != dbAccount.getAccountStatusHistory()) {

        logger.error("getAccountStatusHistory not null");
        dbAccount.getAccountStatusHistory().add(accountStatusHistory);

    } else {
        logger.error("getAccountStatusHistory is null");
        List<AccountStatusHistory> accountStatusHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        accountStatusHistoryList.add(accountStatusHistory);
        dbAccount.setAccountStatusHistory(accountStatusHistoryList);
    }

    Account createdAccount = saveAccount(dbAccount);
    logger.debug("createdAccount.getAccountId()={}", createdAccount.getAccountId());
    return createdAccount;

}
```

And the final method is

```
public Account saveAccount(Account dbAccount) {
    try {

        Account createdAccount = accountRepository.save(dbAccount);
        logger.debug("createdAccount.getAccountId()={}", createdAccount.getAccountId());
        return createdAccount;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("ERROR in account creation={}", e);
        throw new InternalServerException(AccountConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                AccountConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_CODE);
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace

> ERROR Throwable={}","stack_trace":"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.adobe.costheta.account.model.db.mysql.Account#1000000080]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.adobe.costheta.account.model.db.mysql.Account#1000000080]\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:400)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:537)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.service.DbService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d6d52b1.generateDirectCustomerAccountEntity()\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.service.DirectCustomerAccountServiceImpl.createDirectCustomerAccount(DirectCustomerAccountServiceImpl.java:158)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.service.DirectCustomerAccountServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$27f4a473.invoke()\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.service.DirectCustomerAccountServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13af2ff1.createDirectCustomerAccount()\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.resource.AccountResource.createAccount(AccountResource.java:93)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.resource.AccountResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dd5cfc46.invoke()\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)\n\tat com.adobe.asr.logging.aspect.ExecutionTimeAspect.logExecutionTime(ExecutionTimeAspect.java:83)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.resource.AccountResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d988334a.createAccount()\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestResponseFilter.java:88)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.adobe.asr.logging.http.servlet.AsrLoggingFilter.doFilter(AsrLoggingFilter.java:69)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.adobe.asr.filter.AsrRequestIdFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrRequestIdFilter.java:99)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.filters.ApiLoggingFilter.doFilter(ApiLoggingFilter.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.adobe.asr.exception.AsrExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(AsrExceptionFilter.java:82)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.adobe.costheta.filters.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:44)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.adobe.costheta.account.model.db.mysql.Account#1000000080]\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:123)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1478)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:512)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3310)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2506)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:533)\n\t... 126 common frames omitted\n","requestId":"f5d17eccdfa90271","Content-Type":"application/json"}

Comment: We have a utility method to generate accountId which ensures that duplicate id is not generated.   Important part is when I comment SetAccountContact method it works when I uncomment that error is thrown.

Comment: Could you please post the entire exception stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace is updated.

Comment: Are you sure `dbService.genarateAccountId(accountCode)` generates a unique ID? It might be that `dbcontact.getAccountContact()` (called inside the method you mention) loads some other `Account`s into the session, one of which happens to have the same `id` as the newly generated one

Comment: I am sure that accountId is always unique.

Comment: Could you try (1) moving `dbAccount.setAccountId(accountId)` to the end of `map` (2)  calling `accountRepository.save(dbAccount);` right **before** that line? I think I can see the problem now, if the suggestion helps then that would confirm my hypothesis

Comment: No luck, still the same error. Jus to re check, I have added dbAccount.setAccountId(accountId) to the end of map method. Secondly accountRepository.save(dbAccount) cant be added before setting accountId right ? Hope i understood u correctly. id is not autogenerated we have to set it before persist.

Comment: No, that was the whole point. Set the `id` **after** persisting. I think you're confused about how the `save` method works. It only marks the entity as being tracked, the actual flushing to the db happens later, usually upon transaction commit

Comment: As an alternative to the above test, you can try making `Account` implement `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable`, returning `true` from `isNew`

Comment: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.adobe.costheta.account.model.db.mysql.Account; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.adobe.costheta.account.model.db.mysql.Account      This error I am getting while setting accountId after persisting.  The other solution implementing org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable, returning true from isNew cant be done since same entity is been referred in many business logic.

Comment: What happens if you implement `Persistable` and assign the id before saving? I know its not the solution, I'm still trying to help you diagnose the symptoms

Comment: No, I meant implementing `Persistable` and assigning the `id` *before* the `save` method. Spring Data JPA decides whether to call `EntityManager.merge()` or `EntityManager.persist()` inside `save`, depending on whether it considers the entity to be new or not. By default, it assumes anything that already has an id cannot be a new entity (and so `merge()` is selected). The point is to force the `save` method to call `persist` rather than `merge`  instead.

Comment: Implementing Persistable and returning true from isNew works fine. But will that affect existing reference to Account object used in creation of  different types of account.

Comment: In that case we are calling save method in update logic too .. How hibernate gonna behaviour in those scenarios ? So in ma case it was merge which is being called instead of persist ? that is the reason why i was getting that error ?

Comment: OK, so that would confirm my hypothesis. I'll post an answer to your question in a little while. I'll try to explain possible alternatives to `Persistable` as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, the answer is going to be a little complicated, but bear with me.

**First of all, the root cause is the manually generated `id`.**

Inside `setAccountContact(...)`, you have: `dbAccountContact.setAccount(dbAccount)` where you assign the `Account` previously created in the outer `map(...)` method. Let's called this account object `A`.

Later on, inside `saveAccount(...)`, you call `accountRepository.save(dbAccount)`. This call returns an `Account` object, which we'll call `B`.

Now, Spring Data JPA repository `save` method decides whether to call `EntityManager.merge()` or `EntityManager.persist()` inside `save`, depending on whether it considers the entity to be new or not. By default, it assumes anything that already has an id cannot be a new entity (and so `merge()` is selected).

When you pass an unmanaged/detached entity to `EntityManager.merge()`, a *copy* of the input entity is always returned. This means that `A != B`.

This is precisely where the `different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session` error is coming from. At transaction commit, you have different copies (the `A` assigned to `dbAccountContact` and the `B` just returned from `save`) of `Account` with the same `id`. Such a state is forbidden in JPA, because JPA doesn't know which version of the object 'wins'. Note that if `save` called `EntityManager.persist()`, no copy would be created, the original `Account` would simply become managed, so the issue wouldn't exist.

**Ways you can solve this problem:**

1. Encapsulate the id-generating capabilities of the underlying database in the form of a Hibernate's sequence generator

You're using `dbService.genarateAccountId(accountCode)`, so I'm assuming there's some custom logic involved and a simple `@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE|AUTO|TABLE)`  won't do. However, those are *not* the only options. See [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/) on how to roll out a customized id generator.

(note: the article suggests to inherit from `SequenceStyleGenerator`, which allows you to concatenate a DB sequence with extra content. **However**, if you implement the more general `IdentifierGenerator`, you'll get access to `SessionImplementor`, which you can use to call *arbitrary* SQL on your DB, not necessarily accessing a sequence).

Personally, **I strongly recommend this option**. However, if that doesn't work for you, then:

2. Use `Persistable`

You can implement `Persistable` and implement `isNew()` to tell Spring Data 'hey, don't be fooled by the id, this object is in fact a new object!'. As you already noticed, doing so solves the problem. Of course, the caveat is *any* instance of `Account`, new or old, will now be considered new by `JpaRepository.save()`. This will create problems if you ever **merge detached `Account` entities elsewhere in our app** (If not, you should be completely fine).

3. Rearrange your code to `save` the `Account` early

Another solution is to call `accountRepository.save()` **as soon as** you create the new account inside `map`:

```
Account dbAccount = new Account(); //Account A created
dbService.genarateAccountId(accountCode);
dbAccount = accountRepository.save(dbAccount); //Account A passed to `save`, `save` returns Account B, Account A is not referenced anywhere anymore, problem solved
```

(you could also call `save` a bit later, but necessarily *before* the problematic `dbAccountContact.setAccount(dbAccount)` line).

This avoids the problem of two `Account` copies being present in the persistence context. **However**, you may run into problems when executing queries, e.g. in this line:

```
Contact dbcontact = contactRepository.findByEmail(email);
```

before reaching this line, you need to make sure all the required associations of `Account` are populated correctly because at this point, the persistence context will be flushed. If you cannot satisfy this requirement, the alternative is to use `FlushMode.COMMIT` with the query method itself:

```
@QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT") }) //  this prevents a flush before querying
Contact findByEmail(String email);
```

(not sure if the above issue applies to you, but in case it does, simply rearrange your code so that saving the current state of `Account` does not trigger constraint violations *before* executing any queries. Alternatively, consider calling the query method *before* you even `save` the `Account`). Also, don't worry about cascading the `persist` operation in this scenario. The cascade should still happen upon transaction commit.

4. Simply inject `EntityManager` into your service and call `EntityManager.persist()` yourself

Of course, this introduces a leaking abstraction, so you should probably not consider this solution seriously. I'm just saying it would work.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for the detailed explanation. This was very helpful. I could not implement 1st  solution since I ID generation in our system has complex logic and it used by many dependent services. 2) Since we were not sure about the detached objects anywhere in the application i did not give a try for that. 4)  We are using JPA crud repository to perform crud operations and existing code standards would not allow me to implement that.

Comment: The last option to rearrange the code helped me to solve the issue. the good part is I did not even get the exception while loading contact based on email which you warned me to take care of. Finally the rearrangement of code looks like this,  

  Account dbAccount = dCustomerModelToEntityMapper.map(source,headers);
  dbAccount = saveDirectCustomerAccount(source, dbAccount, headers, workflowId);
  setAccountContact(dbAccount, source, headers);
  return dbAccount;
 }                   After persisting I set the account contact. Once again thank u so much

Comment: I would like to propose another option: One can use Springs Version-Property inspection as well. It precedes the Id-Property check. Please take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies for details.

Answer (score 0):

this will work to resolve to **DataIntegrityViolationException**

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually for me I found another solution.

I had this issue when updating an entity.
Firstly I queried entity by id.
Secondly I implicitly updated that entity.

And the solution was to use explicit call to save the entity.

From

```
Entity entityFromDb = repository.findById(id)
mapper.merge(newEntity, entityFromDb)
```

To

```
Entity entityFromDb = repository.findById(id)
mapper.merge(newEntity, entityFromDb)
repository.save(entityFromDb) // so here is the solution
```